# Spatial distance contraction and time dilation

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames

Suppose Bob is travelling in a 100 meters long spaceship at velocity of 150000000 m/s (almost 0.5c) in Michael's frame of reference. Michael is located on a planet which has diameter of 1200000000 meters.

Michael sees the spaceship length contracted and it also appears to be only 86.6 meters long. Michael also notices that the spaceship clock is running slow. For every 1.2 seconds on Michael's clock, the spaceship clock only registers 1 second.

Michael knows the distance of his planet from one side to another, i.e. the diameter, which is 1200000000 meters. Michael is also aware of spaceship's length contraction and time dilation. Michael would conclude that the spaceship would take 9.6 seconds according to the spaceship's clock to diametrically travel from one edge of his planet to the other end.

Bob on the spaceship only registers 6.928 seconds to diametrically travel across the planet because the space is also contracted in the frame of reference of spaceship and it sees only distance of 1039200000 meters.

Michael could only see the spaceship length contracted and he was not aware that the space itself was also length contracted for the spaceship. Would Michael come to know of this fact about spacial distance contraction only when he notices that the spaceship is able to travel more distance for each unit time on spaceship clock? Please note that Michael can see the spaceship clock.

Comment: Your numbers all look correct, but I don't quite understand your question. Both observers agree on their relative velocity of 0.5c, even though they disagree on length & time measurements. Bear in mind that Michael has to take into account the light travel time of the signals from Bob's clock before he can do any speed calculations using those time durations.

Comment: BTW, that's a pretty big planet! If it has the same mean density as Earth, its surface gravity is over 94 *g*.

Comment: **Part 1:** "_Both observers agree on their relative velocity of 0.5c, even though they disagree on length & time measurements._" When you look at my original question you would see that I said "velocity of 150000000 m/s (almost 0.5c)". I purposely stated the velocity in m/s and then for clarity said 0.5c. If the observers are moving relative to each other, their "meters" and "seconds" are different. So, if Bob who is on the spaceship tells Michael that my spaceship is moving at 150000000 m/s then Michael would not agree on this speed because in Michael's **Cont'd**

Comment: reference frame spaceship's meters and seconds are not the same. I think Michael would conclude that the speed is 150000000*0.866/(1.2)=108250000 m/s in his reference frame. Yes, each observer would agree on the speed of light and perhaps that's why velocities are stated as fractions of 'c' like 0.5c to avoid confusion. But the problem is that I don't understand how such a 'light' speedometer works.

Comment: **Part 2:** Suppose that the planet is flat and spaceship is not flying that high. Please check this image: https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/2612/8QNlDm.jpg . When the spaceship is at point, say, 'A', Bob or spaceship sends a signal to Michael. The signal contains information about speed and location on the planet. We can say 'A' is sign post erected on planet. Since, the planet's diameter is 1200000000 meters therefore distance between 'A' and 'B' is 150000000 meters in Michael's reference frame. When spaceship is at location A, it sends a signal to Michael telling him **Cont'd**

Comment: I'm going to cross your planet and my stopwatch reads 0 seconds and my location is A. The signal would take 2 seconds to get to Michael. When spaceship is location B, it sends signal saying my that my location is B and my stopwatch now reads 0.8333 seconds. The spaceship only measured distance of 129900000 meters between locations A and B due to space contraction. Wouldn't Michael be scratching his head when he reads the message that the stopwatch only read 0.8333 seconds at location B? Michael had calculated that from A to B it would take 150000000/108250000=1.386 **Cont'd**

Comment: seconds. I know what I'm saying is wrong but I don't see where the confusion lies.

Comment: All of this additional info doesn't belong in the comments. It should be edited into your question.

Comment: But anyway, in Michael's frame, Bob's ship moves at .5c, and in Bob's frame, Michael's planet is moving at .5c. But Bob & Michael do *not* agree on which events are simultaneous. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity